# Thymeleaf - Spring MVC. Form backing bean with boolean and checkboxes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Iam trying post a simple form to a spring controller using a thymeleaf. The backing bean includes a boolean value which is mapped to a checkbox in the template using th:field inside of a th:object tag. When I take a look at the rendered html DOM, spring mvc is adding an hidden input field, where the name is _attributeName. The name of the main input field is generated as attributeName. Now when Iam trying to post the form it aborts with a 400 because the request parameter _attributeName cant be mapped to a backing bean object (simply doesnt exist). So in addition the request wohld include attributeName as well as _attributeName. Why is this happening?

Comment: It's more likely that people will ignore your question if they don't see any code in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So i finally solved it. The Problem was, that I used boolean instead of Boolean and my getter where named like isEnabled instead of getEnabled. This seemed to cause the problem with the mapping between the form element and the backing bean.

Comment: Your post saved me hours.  I would like to add though, that I only got my checkboxes working after creating getIsEnabled style getters.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example, i.e. controller, template with a form with only checkbox and submit and a backing bean with only a boolean?

Comment: Your post saved me hours. I used boolean instead of Boolean

Comment: Life Saver Man, Didnt know, what was wrong with the thing.

Answer (score -2):

Tried solution mentioned by Vinc, but didn't work for me. However below worked for me.

**Controller**

```java
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    private String index(DemoDto demoDto){
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    private String receiveValues(DemoDto demoDto) {
        System.out.println(demoDto);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

**DTO**

```java
public class DemoDto {
    private String name;
    private boolean global;

    //getter setter for name

    public boolean isGlobal() {
        return global;
    }
    public void setGlobal(boolean global) {
        this.global = global;
    }

    //toString()
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/}" th:method="post" th:object="${demoDto}">
        <label>Enter Name:</label> 
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" name="name"> 
        <br/>
        <label>Global</label>
            <input type="checkbox" th:field="${demoDto.global}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

Here most important is how you define `th:field="${demoDto.global}"`. Both `$` as well as object name `demoDto` are required here.

Generated html code will be.

```html
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <label>Enter Name:</label> 
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""> 
        <br/>
        <label>Global</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="global1" name="global" value="true"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="_global" value="on"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

When submitted from ui received:

```
DemoDto [name=Dev, global=true]
```